# check if new reference has been created in redux selector

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have the problem where I receive in my `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` a new reference of the object in the incoming `this.props`, so even the values are equal, I get misleading object comparisons when I compare `this.props` with the `prevProps` object.
To track this, I'd like to know why this happens and I think is because of [Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#creating-a-memoized-selector).

So, consider the typicall scenario

```
class FooComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    ....
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    stateSlice: getStateSlice(state)
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    ...
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FooComponent))
```

For the scenario of a complex app, big global state and complex `getStateSlice` function, I'd like to know if a new reference has been created.

I tried to compare `getStateSlice(state)` with `state.stateSlice` in the `mapStateToProps` with a `refCheck` function like this:

```
function refCheck(state, props) {
    if (props.stateSlice === getStateSlice(state)) {
        console.log('sameRef!!');
    }
    return getStateSlice(state);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    stateSlice: refCheck(state)
}
```

And everything works, but I keep getting the same **value** props in the `ComponentDidUpdate()` and a different **reference**.
Prof if this is that I obtain in the `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`

```
prevProps === this.props: false
JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(this.props): true
```

How may I check if a new reference is created to evaluate if a selector works correctly and does not create new ref at the state info retrieve step for the same values by mistake? It also'd be helpful to be able to check that at the reducer level and log whether the reducer is creating a new refernce or not.